# Selectable Serialize jQuery UI:: How to display the content within the html tag instead of the index value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, selectable

I'm very new beginner to jquery and I'm using the 'Selectable, Serialize' interaction from jQuery UI.

The interaction shows the index value that the user has selected, but I would like to know how to instead of displaying the index value, display the content that the user has selected.

### so actually its like this

SCRIPT::

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({

  stop: function() {

    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();

    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {

      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );

      result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );

    });

  }

});
```

HTML::

```
<ol id="selectable">

  <li class="ui-widget-content">Watermelon</li>

  <li class="ui-widget-content">Orange</li>

  <li class="ui-widget-content">Guava</li>

  <li class="ui-widget-content">Apple</li>

  <li class="ui-widget-content">Banana</li>

 </ol>
```

The result shown is "You've selected:  #1."

But I would like the result to be displayed as "You've selected:  Watermelon"

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({

  stop: function() {

    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();

    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {

      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
      //this is set by jQuery to be the current item in the each iteration
      //so wrap this in the $.jQuery object and then you will be able to call the jQuery method
      //text() to get the text value
      result.append( " " + $(this).text());

    });

  }

});
```